# Using QTP I am trying to display totaltime but its showing type mismatch

Tags: qtp

```
Dim Starttime,Endtime,Totaltime
Starttime = FormatDateTime (Time, vbShortTime)& Right (Time, 6) ' Full 24 hour time format
msgbox starttime
Endtime = FormatDateTime (Time, vbShortTime)& Right (Time, 6)    ' Short 24 hour time format
msgbox Endtime
Totaltime = Starttime-Endtime
msgbox Totaltime
```

Comment: Well you are trying to subtract a string from a string

Answer (score 2):

Instead use [MercuryTimers](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#OV_Supp_Util/Utility_MercuryTimer.htm?Highlight=MercuryTimers) object which gives you more controls like Start, Stop, Reset, Continue.

```
MercuryTimers("Timer1").Start
...
'YOUR CODE
...
MercuryTimers("Timer1").Stop
Totaltime = MercuryTimers("Timer1").Elapsedtime/1000
If Totaltime > 60 Then
    tempTime = Totaltime/60
    Temp_Arr = split(tempTime,".",-1,1) : Temp2 = "." & Temp_Arr(1)
    msgbox Temp_Arr(0) & " Min, " & Round(Temp2 * 60) & " Sec"
Else
    msgbox Totaltime & " Sec"
End If
```

Comment: +1. I too didn't know about MercuryTimers. But would have just used the "timer" function(only useful until midnight after which it resets). Good to have more options available. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer have helped you than pls accept the answer.